# changing language doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, cookies

I have a website which supports two languages. In Chrome switching languages works great, but in Firefox it doesn't matter which button I click, for "english" or "german" language it always set my language variable for german language which is set by default

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

here is example function where I call getLangCookie function

```
var lang = getLangCookie('lang');
console.log('lang = ', lang);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/menu.xml',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('description ' + lang).each(function () {
            $(this).parent().html($(this).html());
        }
        );
        var menu = [];
        var data = $.xml2json(xml)['#document'];
        that.menu = data.menu;
        console.log('menu = ', that.menu);
    }
}

);
function getLangCookie(lang) {
    var name = lang + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
// by clicking on English button set the cookie value
function onEnglishbtn() {
    setLangCookie("lang", "en", 30);

    document.location.reload();
    var lang = getLangCookie('lang');

    return lang;
}

    function setLangCookie(lang, value, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = lang + "=" + value + "; " + expires;
}
// function onload from index.html setting up the lang by default
window.onload = function () {
    setLangCookie("lang", "de", 30);
    if (typeof window.localStorage !== "undefined" && !localStorage.getItem('visited')) {
        localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
        setLangCookie("lang", "de", 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you change the cookie value?

Comment: I just added a function in the main post

Comment: Does Firefox disable cookie?

Comment: Please add the setLangCookie function to the post as well.

Comment: done! I also added a onload function from my main index.html file

Comment: and yes, cookies in Firefox are enabled

Comment: If is see correct you click the english button change the cookie to 'en' and refresh the page and when the window loaded you set the cookie 'de' I think it could be a problem if you not check is the cookie exist in the onload function and override it.

Comment: ok, but why then Chrome works without any probelm? could you please provide a sample code how to check a cookie

Comment: Use the getLangCookie function and if it returns with empty string no cookie preset.

Comment: may be I'm doing something wrong but it doesnt't work
the _langcookie_ works right but when I'm calling then getLangCookie() before ajax call then I get another language
`window.onload = function () {
        var lang_cookie = getLangCookie('lang');
        console.log('lang_cookie = ', lang_cookie);
        // if cookie doesn't exist
        if (lang_cookie !== null) {
            setLangCookie("lang", "de", 30);
        }
        //  if cookie exists
        else {
            console.log('lang_cookie exists!');
            setLangCookie("lang", lang_cookie, 30);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the ajax request to the onload function as well something like this.

```
function getLangCookie(lang) {
    var name = lang + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
// by clicking on English button set the cookie value
function onEnglishbtn() {
    setLangCookie("lang", "en", 30);

    document.location.reload();
    var lang = getLangCookie('lang');

    return lang;
}

function setLangCookie(lang, value, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = lang + "=" + value + "; " + expires;
}
// function onload from index.html setting up the lang by default
window.onload = function () {
    var lang_cookie = getLangCookie('lang');
    console.log('lang_cookie = ', lang_cookie);
    // if cookie doesn't exist
    if (lang_cookie !== null) {
        setLangCookie("lang", "de", 30);
    } // if cookie exists
    else {
        console.log('lang_cookie exists!');
        setLangCookie("lang", lang_cookie, 30);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/menu.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('description ' + lang_cookie).each(function () {
                $(this).parent().html($(this).html());
            }
            );
            var menu = [];
            var data = $.xml2json(xml)['#document'];
            that.menu = data.menu;
            console.log('menu = ', that.menu);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't do this. these two functions are in two different files with a totally different logic behind them

Comment: Then you should put the cookie check before the ajax request as well.